# How to Remove Left Recursion from this Grammar?

Tags: context-free, formal-grammars, compilers, recursion

How to remove left recursion in the following Grammar:

```
S→Bb/a
B→Bc/Sd/e
```

Im new to this, below is the way I'm doing it:

```
S-> Sd/a
B-> Bc/Bb/e
```

I replaced the values of S and B with Bb and Sd to make the grammar easier to deal with.
Then:

```
S-> aS'
S'-> dS' / ε
```

Is this the correct approach to do this ?

Comment: Now do the same for $B$.

Comment: @vonbrand 

B-> eB' B'-> cB' / dB' / ε Is this the correct way of doing this? Someone told me that I cant replace the values of S and B with Bb and Sd.

Comment: The custom is to use `|` where you're writing `/`.

Answer (score 0):

```
S->Bb|a
B->SdB'|eB'
B'->cB'|ε
```

Comment: We're not looking for an answer that just contains a grammar.  We would like to see explanation, justification, etc.